# How to override html formatting in validation errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the formatting created by rails validations?  My HTML is below, but basically if there's an error it'll format my errors in the built-in rails way... yet I'd like to have it not.  For example, in the below, the password_field would be formatted differently in the event of an error (I don't want that), and the error_message would have additional formatting around it when I'd just like the text of the error message to print.  Any ideas on how to best do this?

Thanks!

-<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= error_message_on :user, :password %>-

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this link in the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#customizing-error-messages-css. This should let you customize the html for the errors however you would like.

This example will leave the html form field exactly the same, even if there are errors.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  %(#{html_tag})
end
```

Next we can add a helper method to render the errors:

```
def custom_error_message_on(object, method)
  errors = object.errors.on(method)
  "#{ERB::Util.html_escape(errors.is_a?(Array) ? errors.first : errors)}"
end
```

I basically just stripped down what the normal [error_message_on](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper.html#M001693) does for what you need.

Now you can use it in your page like so:

```
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= custom_error_message_on :user, :password %>
```

and the html output will be something like this:

```
<input type='password' name='password' />
Your password is required
```

This will let you put whatever extra markup you need and wont restrict you to doing it one way for all your forms.

Another thing you might want to take a look at if you have a number of forms that follow the same pattern is the custom form builders http://ramblingsonrails.com/how-to-make-a-custom-form-builder-in-rails.

Comment: thanks, John - to add to my questions, though:  What if I have extra HTML that I want to put between the form and the error, and that HTML will differ from form to form?  In the above example, it requires me to put a <br> between input box and error, but in my application, what's in between will be different for each form.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments, hopefully that helps.